# How to force google to remove the outdated or removed pages from indexing

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, googlebot

Although it appears a duplicate question, it is slightly different, application developed using html/javascript contains "html" extension for all the pages and when it is migrated using frameworks like angular/react the older version html suffixed pages can be removed temporarily from the search console.

[image: Temporary removal option for the site owners]

How can we remove some pages completely instead of temporary removal. We have included `404` within a `<h1>` tag so that the crawlers can identify that it got removed in our new version but still when we try with "Remove outdated content"(which claims to remove the content permanently) the request status is getting denied.

[image: request status of outdated content]

Is there anything available like "Remove outdated content" for the site owners to remove the pages from index completely as this might cause the visitors to view 404 page from google results with the newer version deployed on the hosting service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 404 isn't only a phrase you put in your `h1` tag, it's an HTTP status code that your server needs to send when the page is requested. If your server doesn't send a 404 HTTP status code, then the search indexing bot will not recognize that the page is removed, which is what I believe is happening here. If a 404 status code is infeasible for any reason, you could use a `meta robots noindex` tag in your page's HTML code instead, which is less semantically correct but will also indicate to search engines that no page at that url should be indexed.

Comment: Do you have access toe the webserver? Can you use rewrites through .htaccess or the like?